How to set permission so that `du` can be run as some user on external drive directories that are owned by multiple other users?
I am trying to use the du command as one user from inside a docker container (Telegraf) to get the disk usage of various directories on an external NFS-mounted drive. My set up looks like this:

Both the docker containers run their services as the same user (monitor_usr:monitor_usr, UID/GID 1001:1001). The problem is essentially that all various files and directories on the external drive are created/managed by a variety of different users, and are therefore owned by different users. However, the du command requires executable permissions in order to get the correct disk size. The user monitor_usr doesn't own or have executable permissions on all the files created in the external drive by other users.
My thoughts:

I don't want to just chmod all files on the drive to allow all users access. I also don't think this approach would work anyway, because as new files are created on the external drive they would also need chmod after each creation.
I thought about creating a group (e.g. drive_usrgrp), with the intention of having all users that need to use the drive have full permissions. However, I think the issue would remain when new users (in other containers/VMs) create new files - they would again need to be chmod. Also, when I start the docker container currently with user monitor_usr:monitor_usr I would then have to start it something like monitor_usr:drive_usrgrp.

What's a good way to set these permissions up properly?


However, I think the issue would remain when new users (in other containers/VMs) create new files - they would again need to be chmod

Define ACLs using setfacl. You can add multiple users or groups to the ACL, and you can define "default" ACLs on a directory that will be inherited by newly created subdirectories (and files).
For the main group:
setfacl -R -m g::rX,d:g::rX /foo

For an additional entry:
setfacl -R -m g:monitor:rX,d:g:monitor:rX /foo

Unlike Windows ACL inheritance, setting a "default" ACL only affects new items created in the future, not existing ones, so the examples here duplicate it as both a normal ACL and as a default ACL.
Note: When an ACL is set, the "group" permissions in ls/chmod no longer control only the main group permissions – they will control the "mask" entry that limits all ACLs – so don't chmod g-x even if you use the 2nd example. The main group entry remains accessible via setfacl g::.

Also, when I start the docker container currently with user monitor_usr:monitor_usr I would then have to start it something like monitor_usr:drive_usrgrp.

Processes can have auxiliary groups, not just the one primary group.

Thanks for this. Its helpful. I am confused how to implement it for my specific case. Are you saying I should indeed create a group for external drive users? For clarity, my drive is actually an NFS drive which is exported from another VM, and then network mounted on the docker host. Should I run setfacl on the NFS-server machine, or the docker host, or inside the docker container?

Actually, after reading a little, it seems like the fact that the drive is an NFS mounted share might have actually been crucial information. Apologies for not mentioning this in the OP before. Edited the OP now. Does it change things?

I don't quite remember if Linux can handle it – NFSv3 has no ACLs at all; NFSv4 has its own Windows-like ACL system that you might be able to use (but the tools are different), Linux servers don't support it but e.g. FreeBSD servers do... If the server is Linux but you can run setfacl directly on the NFS server, that might work, as the enforcement is done server-side.
